Scheduled Cloud Flow - How to send an email to a list of people in Sharepoint List Person column?
I have a Sharepoint list that has these columns:

Step (integer starts from 1)
Document (lookup column from a Sharepoint Library)
Assigned User (Person/Group Column that Allow Multiple Selections).

Example of the list:
     Step   Document   Assigned User
     1      Doc1       Smith,John Smith, Mary
     2      Doc1       Smith, Anne

I posted a similar question, but doing it from the Canvas app.
But, this time, for another process, I need to do it in Scheduled Cloud Flow.
In Scheduled Cloud Flow, how can I send an email to the list of users for Document Doc1,Step 1 ie. send an email to Smith,John and Smith, Mary ?
I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z-xtKcRnyE, but that process is triggered when an item is added to a Sharepoint list.
In my case, I need to "Get Items" from the Sharepoint List and set Filter Query to Document eq 'Doc1' and Step eq 1.
In the next steps like Compose, as soon as I select anything from "Get Items" like "Assigned User", it puts the Compose inside "Apply to each", and I can't move it outside the "Apply to each".
When I run it, it didn't send me any email. Thank you


----Update with resolution----
I found my issue.
I failed to mention that Document is a lookup column.
So, in "Get Items", i need to set the filter query to this:
Document/Title eq 'Doc1' and Step eq 2


Are you trying to send email to 'John' and 'Smith' or is it an email? because you cannot send email to a name right?

I am trying to send an email to both persons  Smith,John and Smith, Mary

Can you show the inputs of send an email action so we can see what is being passed in the 'To' field.

I actually hard coded the "To" field of the send email to my email address, just to see if i get any email or not, and I didn't.

Can you share hardcoded value?

something like john.smith@mycompany.com

I resolved the issue. I edit my original post with the resolution
